# input cannot be empty but console.log is still running

Tags: javascript, html

The code is works but how can I stop the console when input empty is? Console side responds in all conditions.

```
<label>Enter your name: </label> <br> 
<input type="text" id="myText"> <br> 
<button type="button" onClick="click()"id="myButton">Submit</input>
```

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
  var myName = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  console.log("Hello", myName);
}

var input = document.getElementById("myText");

addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();

    document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    if (document.getElementById("myText").value.length == 0) {
      alert("You must write something!")
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting the hello output in the console.

Comment: `I'm still getting the hello output in the console.` Yes sure, because you don't do any test there to check if the `input` is empty. But you do the test in the `keyup` part so what is your problem doing that exact same test in your `onclick` part for the console output?

Answer (score 1):

The `console.log` call is inside the onclick function, which you call before you check whether there was any content in the input.

It would make more sense to do your if statement inside the onclick function to get the desired result.

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function(){

  var myName = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  if (myName.length == 0) {
    console.log("Hello",myName );
    alert("You must write something!")
  }
    
}

var input = document.getElementById("myText");

addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {

  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
 
      event.preventDefault();
 
      document.getElementById("myButton").click();

  
  }

});
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are checking if myText is empty after print it to console.
I think this should be work :

```
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    if(document.getElementById("myText").value.length == 0)
    {
       alert("You must write something!")
       return ;
    }else{
       event.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need a couple of changes

```js
// JavaScript code needs to run after dom has fully mounted 
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

  const myButton = document.getElementById(“myButton”);

  const myText = document.getElementById(“myText”);

  // event listeners 
  myButton.addEventListener(“click”, eventForButton);
  
  myText.addEventListener(“keydown”, (e)=> {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
 
          e.preventDefault();
           // if input doesn’t have a value some browsers return null
           // that’s why is better to have a falsely comparison 
          if(!e.target.value) {
             alert("You must write something!")
             return ;
          }

          // you need to click the button after the validation, not before as you have it
          myButton.click();
      }
  });
});
```